# Trying to build a line chart in python - with filters based on one column and the average taken for the lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have data I am pulling from Draftkings - live basketball scores that show the original spread, the live spread, the spread variance, the half, and the time remaining. I have live scripts pulling in this information and then appending it into one dataframe. I want to use this dataframe that contains all the info to run anaysis on while the game is being played. So I would like to see the line variance across the time remaining. My problem has been that when there are two games on at once, which is often in sports, I want to be able to quickly filter on the game I'm trying to see the line variance on. I would also like to be able to filter on the half that the game is in, so I am sure I am seeing first half or second half data. I don't really know how to do this. I also need to be sure I am taking the average of the line variance. As my data is being pulled from Draftkings, when there are commercial breaks or halftime, I get the same time pulled so when I first tried to make this I was getting a sum or something of my line variance. I will show the code I have been using below. Thanks everyone!

```py
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      
today = date.today()
    
path_to_file = f'C:/Users/X/Desktop/Gambling Data/Consolidated_Data_{today}.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8')
data.drop(data.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True) 
print(data)
    
# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
# use unstack()
data.groupby(['Time Remaining','Team']).count()['Line Variance'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Time Remaining', fontsize = 14)
# set axis labels
ax.set_ylabel('Line Variance', fontsize = 14)
# set markers
markers = ['o', 's', 'd', '^', 'v']
for i, line in enumerate(ax.get_lines()):
    line.set_marker(markers[i])
    
# update legend
ax.legend(ax.get_lines(), data['Team'], loc='best', ncol=2)
    
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about that your intention is legal, but that is not my job. However for example in my country the website is blocked, how am I supposed to help if I cant see any data? Even if I was, you should always add data necessary to solve your problem within the question. Please edit it with all necessary data.

Comment: I am from a legal state. Everything is legal. No idea what you mean to add more data - I sort of described everything.

Comment: Added in a picture of the data

Comment: two approaches were pooing to my mind: 1) use a recursive definition of the mean & standard deviation. This is efficient in terms of calculation. It updates both values at every new point. create a function with 4 values (mean + std of first &2nd half). Second idea: why not use slicing? (BTW you can pull the actual time also from the match, right?). However, if you go with slicing, using a proper database would most certainly be a better idea (if efficiency and scaling is a real issue)

Comment: I'm very new to Python - how do I do slicing or a recursive definition of the mean?